# javascript function completion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following lines of code. The issue is that the function GetScore() takes some time to complete (about 2 seconds). what I want to do is set the score header accordingly. The issue right now is that execution goes to line 3 and score is computer sometime later on. How could I "wait" for score to be ready and only the execute line 3.

```
$("#ScoreHeader").html('Calculating...');
score = GetScore();
$("#ScoreHeader").html('Done');
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, there is a very efficient pattern that you can use to simplify the interface of asyncronous functions (usually ajax).

```
function getScore() {
    return $.ajax({...}); //$.ajax returns a promise/deferred object
}
```

Then you can do something like

```
getScore().done(function (score) {
});
```

I strongly advise you to read about the [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object in jQuery.

EDIT: If you are not performing an ajax request but use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` instead to process the data in an asynchronous way, you could still use the `Deferred` object.

Here's **[an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jr7nL/)** where we have a function that sums values asynchronously and returns a `Deferred` object that allows the client code to efficiently handle the control flow.

```
function sumValuesAsync(values) {
    var deferred = arguments[1] || $.Deferred(),
        i = arguments[2] || 0,
        sum = arguments[3] || 0;

    sum += values[i];

    if (++i === values.length) {
        deferred.resolve(sum); //notice observers that the process is completed
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            sumValuesAsync(values, deferred, i, sum);
        }, 500);
    }

    return deferred;
}

sumValuesAsync([1, 1, 1, 1]).done(function (total) {
    console.log(total);
});
```

Comment: I am not doing any ajax requests, just some calculations that take longer, so I am just wondering how I could use ajax code?

Comment: @user1144596, Your calculations are using setTimeout or setInterval right? Otherwise the code would be synchronous and you would not need this.

Comment: basically, GetScore computes the location of several objects on a canvas object, but it is coded to be synchronous, then i code that executes and updates a image flip counter. I want to show some activity on screen while the image flip counter function is waiting for data. i don't have setTimeout in GetScore but i could recode it that way. deferred seems interesting and will give it a try

Comment: Could you post the implementation of the `GetScore` function, because if the function is synchronous, the code gets executed from top to bottom and they way you wrote your example should be working. Perhaps you are not giving us enough information to help you adequately.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to refactor GetScore to take a callback function.

Define `GetScore` like this:

```
function GetScore(cb){
    var score = ... // the score calculation logic
    cb(score);
}
```

And then you can do

```
$("#ScoreHeader").html('Calculating...');

var score;
GetScore(function(data){
    score = data;
    $("#ScoreHeader").html('Done');
});
```

Comment: `score = GetScore(...)` makes no sense with a callback-oriented async API.

Comment: @plalx Thanks. Updated, I was not processing somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If `GetScore()` is an asychronous function that doesn't stop execution until it's done (which your description makes it sound like it is), then you can't pause javascript execution until it's done.

You would need to delve into the details of how `GetScore()` is implemented and create a notification (callback) inside of GetScore() that will get called when it's actually complete.  If `GetScore()` uses AJAX to retrieve the score, then the core AJAX implementation will have a notification when it's actually done and you can use that to trigger your own callback.